# Reindex a Pandas series finding nearest date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas time series that looks like this:

```
In [1]: ser1
Out[1]: 
Date
2005-12-31    11382000
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

I would like to reindex it, using the index of another time series:

```
In [2]: ser2
Out[2]: 
Date
2005-12-20    14.13
2005-12-21    14.22
2005-12-22    14.30
2005-12-23    14.35
2005-12-27    14.32
2005-12-28    14.32
2005-12-29    14.23
2005-12-30    14.19
2006-01-03    14.48
2006-01-04    14.54
2006-01-05    14.68
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

But when I use

```
ser3 = ser1.reindex(ser2.index)
```

I get

```
In [4]: ser3
Out[4]: 
Date
2005-12-20   NaN
2005-12-21   NaN
2005-12-22   NaN
2005-12-23   NaN
2005-12-27   NaN
2005-12-28   NaN
2005-12-29   NaN
2005-12-30   NaN
2006-01-03   NaN
2006-01-04   NaN
2006-01-05   NaN
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Notice that the item from ser1 having a date of '2005-12-31' does not appear in ser3, because ser2's index did not include 2005-12-31.  I would like to put ser1's values on the next available date in ser2's index.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want NaNs or the values from s2?

Comment: NaN's are fine for my purposes here.  It's more that I want to be sure ser1 values are in ser3 as of the next available date.

Answer (score 3):

The following will allow you to fill to the nearest forward date if its a `nan` (otherwise it will take the value at that index). (if you want the nearest backward date, you can use method `bfill`). IIRC this is still an open issue in pandas as its a bit non-trivial (and in theory should be a filling method, e.g. 'nearest'), but need a PR for that!

```
In [25]: ser1 = Series(100000,index=[Timestamp('20051231')])

In [26]: ser1
Out[26]: 
2005-12-31    100000
dtype: int64

In [27]: ser2
Out[27]: 
0
2005-12-20    14.13
2005-12-21    14.22
2005-12-22    14.30
2005-12-23    14.35
2005-12-27    14.32
2005-12-28    14.32
2005-12-29    14.23
2005-12-30    14.19
2006-01-03    14.48
2006-01-04    14.54
2006-01-05    14.68
Name: 1, dtype: float64

In [28]: ser1.reindex(ser2.index,method='ffill',limit=1)
Out[28]: 
0
2005-12-20       NaN
2005-12-21       NaN
2005-12-22       NaN
2005-12-23       NaN
2005-12-27       NaN
2005-12-28       NaN
2005-12-29       NaN
2005-12-30       NaN
2006-01-03    100000
2006-01-04       NaN
2006-01-05       NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much.  I agree that it'd be nice to have a 'nearest' method built-in (doesn't seem Pythonic to require cleverness like this) but this solves my problem nicely.

Comment: Rut roh, spoke too soon.  If I use this method and the ser1 date IS in the index, then the ser1 value gets duplicated on the next date.  So this method does not work for a series that has both matched and non-matched dates.  Is there a work-around for that situation?

Comment: that was my comment in the of the response. you might be able to reset these matched ones after the reindex with filling.

Comment: Because the data in ser1 is very sparse, in the end I was able to assume that if two numbers appeared consecutively in ser3, the second was a result of this issue.  So I just looped through ser3 turning that second value to 0.  Would definitely be interested in better approaches though.